# Megento 2: The autoload error

Tags: magento2

I have installed Magento on a test Ubuntu 20.04.01 server via composer with the command:

```
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition ~/magento --ignore-platform-reqs
```

After the installation, I created a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /home/<loginname>/magento/vendor/magento/magento2-base /var/www/html/magento
```

When starting Magento, I receive an autoload error:

> We can't read some files that are required to run the Magento
> application. This usually means file permissions are set incorrectly.

However, the file permissions have been set with the following command:

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo find . -type f -exec chown www-data:www-data {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chown www-data:www-data {} \;
sudo find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
sudo chmod 777 ./app/etc
sudo chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

On [Magento 2 : getting Autoload error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164422/magento-2-getting-autoload-error) the user Sinisa Nedeljkovic wrote that it might be possible that the app/etc/vendor_path.php file is missing.

> If you take a look at vendor/magento/magento2-base/app/autoload.php,
> you'll notice following piece of code:
>
> ```
> define('VENDOR_PATH', BP . '/app/etc/vendor_path.php');
>
> if (!file_exists(VENDOR_PATH)) {
>     throw new \Exception(
>         'We can\'t read some files that are required to run the Magento application. '
>          . 'This usually means file permissions are set incorrectly.'
>     );
> }
> ```
>
> That means that either you don't have app/etc/vendor_path.php file, or
> you're not having enough permissions.

And that is the case: that file is not present in the given folder.

So my question is: how do I get that file? Or copy it from ./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/vendor_path.php?

Feedback is appreciated and with kind regards,
TheStingPilot

Comment: You should link all Magento folder , not only vendor/Magento/magento-base. So all , everything inside like app/ vendor/ etc

Comment: The only vendor_path.php file is found here:
./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/vendor_path.php

And I assume that is not the one we are looking for.

Comment: What I mean this is wrong : sudo ln -s /home/<loginname>/magento/vendor/magento/vendor/magento/magento2-base /var/www/html/magento

Comment: Changing to sudo ln -s /home/<loginname>/magento/vendor /var/www/html/magento did not solve this issue. I had to browse to magento/magento2-base in the browser and I still have the same error message.

Comment: Again you added vendor, link all from Magento not only vendor

Comment: There is only one vendor_path.php in the installation tree:

./vendor/magento/magento2-base/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Framework/Composer/_files/vendor_path.php

If I do a composer install I get all kind of errors about incompatible plugins. That might be possible as I have a Drupal 9 install as well.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that your symbolic link from question is wrong.

Comment: I skipped the symbolic link part. 

So I installed via the command 'sudo composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition /var/www/html/magento --ignore-platform-reqs'

When I browse to https://www.something.eu/magento/vendor/magento/magento2-base/ I get the error message "We can't read some files that are required to run the Magento application. This usually means file permissions are set incorrectly."

I assume the vendor_path.php file is missing. See my topic description. I modified it earlier today. Thank you.

Comment: Why you going to vendor/Magento/magento-base?? Your Magento is in magento/ dir

Answer (score 0):

I have chosen a different approach. I downloaded the tar.gz file, extracted it to \var\www\html\magento and run the installer.

It is not the easiest installation method.

Thanks for your help @BartZalas.

With kind regards,
TheStingPilot

Comment: Please make sure to accept your own answer to close it!